# What's the difference between these 2 Angular code snippets?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm taking a course on AngularJS on Coursera.

The code that the instructor demonstrated in the videos works but for some reason I couldn't get to run on my environment:

Page Layout (partial):

```
<div class="media-body">
<h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
<span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
<span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
<p>{{dish.description}}</p>
</div>
```

Snippet A (demonstrated by professor that I couldn't get to work):

```
var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);        
app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

var dish={ //attributes here; };

this.dish = dish;

});
```

When I would run this function, I don't get any errors in the console but I don't get anything in the display.

Snippet B:

```
var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);
app.controller('dishDetailController', function($scope) {

var dish={ //attributes here;};

$scope.dish = dish;
});
```

When I do it this way, it works. Is there a difference?

Comment: Snippet A is invalid. You need to pass controller dependencies into the function.

Comment: Not sure of the answer but I have also had issue with this, and ended up standardizing on use of `$scope.<etc>`

Comment: Both the examples are valid. The only difference depends on how you refer controller in `view`. It is a mere difference of `controller as vs $scope`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Snippet A is not working most likely because of how the controller is being attached. I am taking a wild guess here.

Where you add `ng-controller` it should probably look something like:

```
 <body ng-controller="dishDetailController as dish">
```

Where as you might have this instead:

```
 <body ng-controller="dishDetailController">
```

Might not be the body tag could be a div or something.

And to make more sense of it inside the snippet A controller try:

```
var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);        
app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

    this = {//attributes here}

});
```

Otherwise you might have to write: `{{dish.dish.stuff}}` inside the template.

Comment: This worked. The controller itself is in the div:
<div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as ddc">

I had to type {{ddc.dish.<attribute>}} for it to display correctly. I think one source of my confusion was overusing 'dish'... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The second snippet (B) is more or less straight out of the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller and is most likely what you are looking for.

In Snippet A, assigning a value via `this` will apply the value directly to the controller itself. This will make it very difficult to access in other contexts, and is most likely not what you want.

Conversely, Snippet B is leveraging the dependency injection provided by AngularJS to ensure that the proper scope is injected into the method. `$scope` has a much more complicated lifecycle, but the important thing to note is that this will make `dish` available outside the context of your controller, such as in an HTML template.

If you need more details, this guy has a way better answer: ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

```
chech this code it is working 

<div ng-app='confusionApp' ng-controller='dishDetailController' class="media-body">
<h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
<span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
<span class="badge">{{dish.price}}</span></h2>
<p>{{dish.description1}}</p>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);
app.controller('dishDetailController', function($scope) {

var dish={ label:'name',name:'afzal',price:'10',description1:'this is the price'};

$scope.dish = dish;
});
</script>
```

Comment: I was able to get this version to work (i.e. using $scope in the function).